# javascript: How to assign value to multidimensional array when keys pattern is held by another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a js function which receives three parameters "(**data**, **treeArray**, **line**)" and returns modified **data** variable

`data: is Multi-dimensional Array`

eg:

```
var data = [ [ 'string', 'string' ,['string','string','string']],[ 'string', 'string' ],'string' ];
```

Other one is

`treeArray: is Single dimensional Array`

eg:

```
var treeArray = [0,1,2];
```

Next is

`line: is String`

eg:

'Hi, I m string'

[For better understanding, Please find the attached screenshots of received data variable and returned data variable :(Where Line variable is placed into data variable on a reference of treeArray, In this case, treeArray is[0,1,2]. So line variable placed in the variable data in such a way,

```
data[0][1][2]="Hi, I m string"
```

)

Consider "start_data" image, where requirement states to place data from line array "Hi, I m string" into the third element within the second position of the First array which is not currently present.

So I need a JS function which creates the third element within the second position of the first array and places the data "Hi, I m string", Similar to "final_data" image.] [ImageAttached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdz4H.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is a difference in data structure between example (multi array) and attached image (object / array mix).

Comment: in your example data[0][1] is a string and not an array

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function modifiedData(data, treeArray, line) {
    var dataToBeModified = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < treeArray.length - 1; i++) {
        dataToBeModified = dataToBeModified[treeArray[i]]
    }

    dataToBeModified[treeArray[treeArray.length-1]] = line;

}


var data = [ [ 'string', ['string', 'String'] ,['string','string','string']],[ 'string', 'string' ],'string' ];  
modifiedData(data, [0,1,2], 'Intekhab');
data;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will create an array if needed and assign the value at the end

```
const defaultValue = (index, indexes, val) => index === indexes.length-1?val:[]

const modifyData = (data, indexes, val) => {
  const selected = indexes.reduce((obj, index) => obj[index] = obj[index] || defaultValue(index, indexes, val), data );
  return data;
}

modifyData(data, treeArray, 'hello');
```